# Using Angular Bootstrap, I am not able to get drop-down items in drop-down Menu

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, dropdown, ng-bootstrap

Here is the related import
`import { NgbModule, NgbDropdownToggle, NgbDropdownMenu, NgbDropdown } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';`

And below is the code I have used. And the code functions for the dropdown but the dropdown-item are not displayed.

```
<li ngbDropdown class="nav-item dropdown ml-0 ml-md-auto" #dropdown="ngbDropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  ngbDropdownToggle>
          <i class="fa fa-user mr-1"></i>
          <span *ngIf="!token"> Account </span>
          <span *ngIf="data.user">{{ data.user.name }}</span>
        </a>
        
        <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdownMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
          <a *ngif="token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/profile" class="dropdown-item" ngbDropdownItem >
            <i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Profile 
          </a>
          <a *ngif="!token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/login" class="dropdown-item" ngbDropdownItem >
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login 
          </a>
          <a *ngif="token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();logout();"  class="dropdown-item" ngbDropdownItem > 
            <i class="fa fa-key" aria-hidden="true"></i>Logout 
          </a>
          <a *ngif="!token" (click)="closeDropdown(dropdown);collapse();" routerLink="/register" class="dropdown-item" ngbDropdownItem >
            <i class="fa fa-group" aria-hidden="true"></i>Register
          </a>  
        </div>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the code.

change `*ngif` on the `<a>` tags to `*ngIf`.

Comment: Yayyy !!! thanks a lot. I would have been trying and searching, my bad. It works now. Thanks.